# Implement 'View in browser' functionality with Newsletter

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are using SDL Tridion 2011. We want to implement "view in Browser" functionality with NewsLetter.

We don't find any proper way to achieve this functionality using Tridion Outbound Mailings.

Can someone please help us to implement this ?

For time being we are publishing a newsletter page and we are linking this page from Newsletter.

Please suggest best approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is the general approach.
There's nothing out the box to link a published web page to a page Outbound Email uses for a mailing.

I think last time I did this we just used a field in the component to allow an editor to enter the full url to the web page, e.g. http://www.blah.com/subscription/email.html. I guess this could be replaced concatenating your site url to the page's PublishLocationUrl or using PageLink if you wanted a managed link.

They then published the web page first, then created a mailing using the same page.

Cheers